# Translating vector elements in R using correspondence table

Tags: r, performance, hash

What is the efficient and simple way in R to do the following:

1. read in two-column data from a file
2. use this information to build some kind of translation dictionary, like a python dict
3. apply the translation to the content of a vector in order to obtain the translated vector, possibly for several vectors but using the same correspondence information

?

I thought that the [hash package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/index.html) would help me to do that, but I'm unsure I perform step 3 correctly.

Say my initial vector is `my_vect` and my hash is `my_dict`
I tried the following:

`values(my_dict, keys=my_vect)`

The following observation make me doubt that I'm doing it in the proper way:

1. The operation seems slow (more than one second on a powerful desktop computer with a vector of 582 entries and a hash of 46665 entries)
2. It results in something that doesn't look homogeneous with `my_vec`: while `my_vec` appeared as "indexed by numbers" (I mean that integer numbers between square brackets appear on the side of the values when displaying the data in the interactive console), the result of calling `values` as above appears to still somehow looks like a dictionary: each displayed translated value has the original value (i.e. hash key) displayed above it. I just want the values.

#### Edit:

If I understand correctly, R has some way of using "names" instead of numerical indices for vectors, and what I obtain using the `values` function is such a vector with names. It seems to work for what I wanted to do, although I imagine it takes more memory than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried libraries hash and [hashmap](https://github.com/nathan-russell/hashmap), and the second seemed more efficient.

A small usage example:

```
> library(hashmap)
> keys = c("a", "b", "c", "d")
> values = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
> my_dict <- hashmap(keys, values)
> my_vect <- c("b", "c", "c")
> translated <- my_dict$find(my_vect)
> translated
[1] "B" "C" "C"
```

To build the dictionary from a table obtained using `read.table`, the option `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` of `read.table` has to be used, otherwise weird things happen (see discussion in the comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38838271/1878788).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `str_replace_all` function from the stringr package?

Let's say you have a dictionary data frame `dict` with columns `original` and `replacement`. The following code replaces all instances of original with replacement in the vector.

```
library(stringr)
translations <- setNames(dict$replacement, dict$original)
new_vect <- str_replace_all(vect, fixed(translations))
```

I'm not sure if it implements hashing, but the underlying expression is in C code from the `stringi` package, so it should be fast.

The only case where that won't work as is, is if some of the words in `original` contain other words in `original`. In this case you'll need to add regular expression start-string (^) or end-string ($) markers to the original strings you want to replace.

`translations <- setNames(dict$replacement, paste0("^", dict$original, "$"))`

Comment: I have my data frame `conversion_table` obtained by reading the 2-column file and from which I could build the hash. so `conversion_table$V1` contains the originals and `conversion_table$V2` contains the replacements. Then I do `translation <- setNames(conversion_table$V2, conversion_table$V1)` and `translation` seems to have a similar format than what I get using `values` on the hash: the replacement values "indexed" by the original values. I gues that is what R calls "names". But then, `str_replace_all` strangely returns me a vector of numbers between quotes. And it is slower than the hash.

Comment: Actually, what I describe in my previous comment is what happens when I use the "^" and "$". If I don't use them, the resulting vector contains a few entries that contain a dot among the numbers. Example:
`[289] "1955"  "1955"  "17361" "17392" "17400" "1963"` vs `[289] "12562.12" "12562.12" "27385.1"  "17392"    "17400"    "1963"` for items 289 to 294 of the translated vector. The original was
`[289] R13A5.12   R13A5.12   R13F6.1    R144.7     R148.7     R74.1`

Comment: The "thing" I had obtained using the hash loooked like so for this same `289:294` slice:
`R13A5.12       R13A5.12        R13F6.1         R144.7         R48.7         R74.1` 
`WBGene00003063 WBGene00003063 WBGene00020064 WBGene00020097 WBGene00020105 WBGene00003073`
(The "keys" being displayed above the corresponding values.)
The "WBGene*" are what I expect after translation.

Comment: When you read the data frame from the file, did you specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`? I believe that's the source of the bug where it returns quoted numbers. But in any, if the hash result is correct and faster, you don't need to use stringr.

Comment: I hadn't used that option. I naively assumed that read.table would simply read the data "normally". I realize now that omitting this option has strange effects in other cases. I tried the hashmap package to build a similar dictionary-like translating device, and omitting to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` resulted in a thing that could operate on data from the original table but resulted in numbers instead of names. Besides, it would fail when I would manually provide elements of my vector. The option fixed this.
So far, using R has been a bit frustrating due to weird behaviours like that.